# "Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string" - What does this error mean and how can I fix it

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, controller, axios

I'm currently creating an application using the Laravel framework and Vue JS.

I have a lot of different 'statuses' e.g. CEO, COO, CFO, Accountant etc. and they all have an ID and a stage_id. My end goal is to use their unique IDs to get their stage IDs and then update their stage IDs to be the same

IMPORTANT: THE $request coming in is in the form of an array of the various status IDs so it could be something like [1,4,6] or even []

This is my controller function:

```
    public function updateStatuses(Request $request, Stage $stage)
    {

    foreach($request as $statusId) {
        Status::forClient()->findOrFail($statusId)->update([
            'stage_id' => $stage->id,
        ]);
    }

    Status::forClient()->all();
    return Status::all();
    }
```

My axios request:

```
        changeStatusIds() {
        var self = this;
        axios.put(window.routes["statusroute"].replace('{stage}', this.selectedStage.id), this.selectedStatuses)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                self.allStatuses = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.error(error);
                if (!!error.response) console.log(error.response);
            });
    },
```

However, I keep getting the error **"Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string"** which I've never come across before and can't seem to debug. Given my current code, how can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087960/object-of-class-symfony-component-httpfoundation-parameterbag-could-not-be-conve)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I don't use the $query key in my function - and given what I currently have it doesn't really provide any specific insight into what I can change

Comment: You should `dd($request)` and search there for what variables you need.

Comment: Ah dd(axios req.) just yields an incredibly long string